# Probability of pulling black balls from the bag

Tags: probability

Bag has 3 balls. 2 white and 1 black. There are 3 pulls. If white is drawn it is removed from the bag. If black is drawn it stays in the bag.

Final outcome can lead to pulling 1, 2 or 3 black balls in total.

Calculating the probability of pulling $3$ black balls in total is easy. $1/3 \cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/3$.

What about the rest? Number of balls can be reduced after a pull if white is drawn.

Comment: There are $2^3=8$ potential patterns of pulls, though white-white-white has a probability of $0$.  You can find the probability of each one (for example white-black-white has a probability of $\frac23 \times \frac12 \times \frac12$) and then add up the cases to answer the question

Comment: Thank you I got 1 black 61%, 2 black 35% and 3 black 4%. is there a general equation for this?

Comment: @Innuendo Your results are correct, as shown in my answer below. I am not aware of a general equation for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ represent the amount of black balls that are drawn. Like you said, the probability of drawing three black balls equals:

$$P(X = 3) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{27}$$

Since the white balls are removed when drawn, we know that the probability of drawing zero black balls equals:

$$P(X = 0) = 0$$

Further, one black ball can be drawn in three ways: $WWB$, $WBW$ or $BWW$. We find:

$$P(WWB) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{3}$$

$$P(WBW) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$$

$$P(BWW) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{9}$$

Thus, the probability of drawing one black ball equals:

$$P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{9} = \frac{11}{18}$$

Then, the probability of drawing two black balls must equal:

$$P(X = 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1) - P(X = 3) = 1 - 0 - \frac{11}{18} - \frac{1}{27} = \frac{19}{54}$$

Indeed, we find:

$$P(WBB) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$$

$$P(BWB) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{9}$$

$$P(BBW) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{27}$$

And thus:

$$P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{27} = \frac{19}{54}$$